# Recording Java code in Sahi

Tags: java, windows-7, automated-tests, sahi

I have installed Sahi Pro 5 on Windows 7. I am able to record my tests as .sah extension which is saved at sahi_pro/userdata/scripts. I am also able to play that file.

As I'm familiar with Java, I want to record my tests as .java extension. How can I record Java code using Sahi?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Shahi's website](http://sahi.co.in/w/java), you should set the controller.mode to "java" (controller.mode=java) in *sahi/config/sahi.properties*, and then restart the software.